# i'm not able to understand why i have to restart the server to see the changes made by a Put request (django rest framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The put request is working, but if i want to see the post updated i have to restart the server.

This is the view function:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from blog.models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@api_view(['PUT'])
    def api_update_post_view(request, Slug):
        try:
            blog_post = Post.objects.get(slug=Slug)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = PostSerializer(blog_post, data=request.data, partial=True)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data['succes'] = 'update successful'
            return Response(data=data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: please include a bit more information of your framework, are you on a development database etc. It makes it easer to understand the potential problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see any special features in your PUT method. So, I suggest you to use **ModelViewSet** instead of creating a basic PUT method yourself. **ModelViewSet** will generate basic CRUD operations for you automatically.
[Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) is the official docs. It should be no problem after you use the **ModelViewSet**.